# How to map() over a list of results and set the array of the results as the state of a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to assign the value of an array to the state in a react project.So,I have defined my state as:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: []
    }
  }
```

Then, I am trying to get the output of an API call and assign it to the state of the react component.I am using the below code to get the desired output.

```
 componentDidMount() {
  readableAPI.getCategories().then(category => {
    if (category) {
        category.categories.map(category => {
          console.log(category.name) //output : react, redux, react-native
          this.setState({ category : category.name})
        })
    }
    console.log(this.state.category) //output: react-native
  })
}
```

What is want is to set the "category" which is the state of the component with an array of the three categories.So,the category state should be: [react,redux,react-native], so that I can use the individual items in the category array to create a button for each item in the category array.So,for now there should be 3 buttons for the three items, i.e.react, redux, react-native.But now,I am not able to assign the items into the category state array. How to do the same?Can anyone please suggest me.

Comment: It would be better to show your desired result or your issue with code, description won't be the right case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array and then set the state as an array and not the individual items everytime. Also setState is async and hence you should use the `callback` to check the updated status.

```
componentDidMount() {
  readableAPI.getCategories().then(category => {
    if (category) {
        const categoryNames = category.categories.map(category => {

          return category.name;
        })

          this.setState({ category : categoryNames}, () => {console.log(this.state.category)})
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: This gives the desired output.Thanks for your help :)